# EigenVectors issue using apache common math3 library

Tags: java, matrix, apache-commons, eigenvector

I'm calculating covariance matrix, eigenvectors and eigenvalues using  [apache commons math3 library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/). so my main function is this (***given a double matrix***):

```
private void coVariance(double[][] matrix) {
        RealMatrix mx = MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(matrix);
        RealMatrix cov = new Covariance(mx).getCovarianceMatrix();
        System.out.println("***************************************");
        System.out.println("Covariance Matrix");
        for (int i = 0; i < cov.getRowDimension(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cov.getColumnDimension(); j++) {
                System.out.print(cov.getEntry(i, j) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("***************************************");
        EigenDecomposition e = new EigenDecomposition(cov);
        double[] arrayEigenValue = e.getRealEigenvalues();
        for (int i = 0; i < e.getRealEigenvalues().length; i++) {
            System.out.println("eigenValue with index " + i + " " + arrayEigenValue[i]);
            RealVector arrayEigenVector = e.getEigenvector(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayEigenVector.getDimension(); j++) {
                System.out.print(arrayEigenVector.getEntry(j) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("***************************************");
    }
```

In order to understand if all is correct i'm using an example which has got ***covariance/eigenValues/eigenVector*** already calculated:

```
2.5,2.4
0.5,0.7
2.2,2.9
1.9,2.2
3.1,3.0
2.3,2.7
2,1.6
1,1.1
1.5,1.6
1.1,0.9
```

It has this results of covariance matrix eigenVectors and eigenValues:

```
0,616555556 0.615444444
0.615444444 0.716555556
```

eigenValues:

```
0.0490833989
1.28402771
```

eigenVectors:

```
1° = -0.735178656 -0.677873309
2° = 0.677873399  -0.735178656
```

**Results of my program:**

Covariance Matrix

```
0.6165555555555556 0.6154444444444446 
0.6154444444444446 0.7165555555555555
```

eigenValues:

```
1.2840277121727839 
0.04908339893832714
```

eigenVectors:

```
1° = -0.7351786555444081  -0.6778733985280118 
2° = -0.6778733985280118   0.7351786555444081
```

*As you can see ,the eigenvectors are different in the sign  of second value of the second eigenVector* **0.7351786555444081**

Could someone explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

Oirc,

If you don't know the mathematically forulatioln of Eigen values in matrices we use a formula to calculate it `|A-L.I| = 0` 
where `A` is matrix (row data )
`L` is (lambda) or constant we are saying as Eigen values here 
I is unit matrix equal to A matrix order.

By this we will get the `L` values that can be positive or negative 
That values we will put to that matrix equation to calulate the vector matrix . 
So after calculation that matrix elements can be positive or negative .

Theoritically : `"-"/"+"`ive sign shows the direction of the vector values.